# How can Firebase acquire data from ESP32/Arduino

Tags: c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, google-cloud-firestore

i'm doing a small IOT project i have 1 master and 2 end node (using rf24l01). Master will receive 2 packages and store in JSON. For the database i'm gonna using Firebase and show it in Node-red. My data like this

```
{
   "1":{ 
      "Temp":"value", 
      "Humid": "value"}
    "2":{
      "Temp":"value",
      "Humid": "value"}
}
```

Like topic's name above, is it like a HTTP or MQTT protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question you are asking is, wether you can access Firebase real time databse through an API? If so, yes, Firebase offers a REST API for its realtime database. You can look up the specification here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data.

If you want to secure your database, you can use the methods described here to authenticate your request with a token. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth